# Flutter: What type of transition is this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

I am practising Cupertino App in Flutter, and I found that there is a page transition that looks like stacking the pages. The following is the transition that I found.

[image: Stack Transition?]

I found a package named [modal_bottom_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet) that looks like have the one I want. The example below the package description is the one I want to implement. I tried it in my code but it doesn't look like what I expected. Is there a package that I'm looking for? or It's already included in the Cupertino package?

Answer (score 1):

It's commonly named Sheet something like the standard [DraggableScrollableSheet][1] or some 3rd-party widget like the following ones  from https://pub.dev/

1. [cupertino_modal_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/bottom_sheet_expandable_bar) (This one is exactly like the animation)
2. [modal_bottom_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet) (This one is exactly like the animation)
3. [awesome_select](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_select)
4. [backdrop_modal_route](https://pub.dev/packages/cupertino_modal_sheet)
5. [bottom_sheet_expandable_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/bottom_sheet)
6. [bottom_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/backdrop_modal_route)
7. [just_bottom_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/just_bottom_sheet)
8. [sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/sheet)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's two things happening at once:

1. You show a modal bottom sheet (and the package you chose is great
   for that).
2. You scale down everything that is below it and round the corners.

I'm not sure if there's a package to do this out of the box.